# How to store a value in a session?

Tags: php, html

I am displaying the user names as links on a `php` page like this which on clicking navigates on particular user home page:

```
$msql=$db->prepare("SELECT * from users where id=? order by id desc");
$msql->bind_param("i",$user_id);
$msql->execute();
$msql = $msql->get_result();
$msql = $msql->num_rows;

while($usercount=$msql->fetch_assoc())
  {
 $Email = $usercount['email'];
  $FirstName = $usercount['first_name'];
  $LastName = $usercount['last_name'];
?>


<strong><a href="?navigate=true" class="post_user" id="post_user" data-emailID="<?php echo $Email; ?>"><?php echo $FirstName.' '.$LastName;?></a></strong>

<?php

}
?>
```

And for the navigation to the user home page on clicking the link, I am using like this :

```
<?php

  if(isset($_GET['navigate']) && $_GET['navigate'] == "true"){

      $_SESSION['email'] = $Email;
      header('location: nextpage.php');
  }

?>
```

So my page looks like this as link

```
user1
user2
user3
.
.
.
usern
```

My issue is whenever I click on any of the links it always stores the first email in the session variable.

So, if I output the SESSION in nextpage.php

```
echo $_SESSION['email'];
```

it always echoes the first link `email`.

My guess for this because of the while loop I am using it always picks up the first link data and stays with it, but my question is how do i get the data for others as well. I want to navigate to that user page for which the link is clicked and that can only be done if I get the correct email on clicking the link.

Comment: @Anant : didn't get you

Comment: no, my table contains multiple rows with this user_id, it is not a primary key because of some reason, so it fetches all the rows with $user_id

Comment: yes, I have done it this way internally; it is not exactly a user table rather think of it as a table with foreign keys

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116537/discussion-between-bishwaroop-chakraborty-and-anant).

Comment: ah, that worked, I didn't  use your entire approach though, updating the anchor tag to yours worked just fine. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As you said `id` is not primary key, and i assume that your same `id` will contain different `emails`, you have to do below changes:-*

```
<?php
$msql=$db->prepare("SELECT * from users where id=? order by id desc");
$msql->bind_param("i",$user_id);
$result = $msql->execute(); // assign to a variable
//$msql = $msql->get_result(); //you are over-writing to one variable which is not correct
//$msql = $msql->num_rows; //you are over-writing to one variable which is not correct

while($usercount=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $Email = $usercount['email'];
    $FirstName = $usercount['first_name'];
    $LastName = $usercount['last_name'];
?>
<strong><a href="?navigate=true&email=$Email" class="post_user" id="post_user" data-emailID="<?php echo $Email; ?>"><?php echo $FirstName.' '.$LastName;?></a></strong> <!-- send mail id to the url too otherwise how's you will get the email id to save it into SESSION-->

<?php } ?>
```

AND

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['navigate']) && $_GET['navigate'] == "true"){
        $_SESSION['email'][] = $_GET['email']; // assign each mail to SESSION ARRAY not SESSION variable
        header('location: nextpage.php');
    }

?>
```

AND

```
echo "<pre/>";print_r($_SESSION['email']); //to see all emails.
```

*Note:- You have to write  `session_start();` on top of your `php` page just after `<?php` if you want to work with `SESSION` on that page.*

Comment: Don't forget `session_start()` ;-)